# PHP & XML How to display data

Tags: php, xml

I'm not very experienced when it comes to XML, I'm looking for a simple php code that can display certain information from an XML file. This file to be exact:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <TITLE>THIS</TITLE>
    <TITLE2>THIS AGAIN</TITLE2>
</Response>
```

Any help would be great, Thanks!

(P.S I just want to simply echo the 2 fields out)

Comment: possible duplicate of [A simple program to CRUD node and node values of xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SimpleXml Working Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893024/basic-simplexml-working-example)

Comment: *(reference)* http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), it's pretty easy and straight forward!

Your example would look like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);

echo $xml->title;
echo $xml->title2;
```

Comment: if it is a file look at simplexml_load_file