# Classify the values of an array in ascending order

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I wish classify the values of my table in ascending order to be able to use them in a variable $distancecp.
My var_dump finds my values well but I can not classify them in ascending order.

```
$select100=mysqli_query($conn,$select10);
while($asso = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select100)) {
    $distancecp1 = getDistance(''.$villeselect.', '.$cpselect.'',''.$asso['ville'].', '.$asso['codep'].'');
    $distancecp2 = array($distancecp1);
    var_dump($distancecp2);
    foreach($distancecp2 as $distancecp) {
    }
}
```

Results of `var_dump($distancecp2)` :

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[8]
      public 0 => string '68526' (length=5)

array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[10]
      public 0 => string '71824' (length=5)

array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
      public 0 => string '67536' (length=5)

array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[9]
      public 0 => string '33902' (length=5)
```

I tried :

```
$select100=mysqli_query($conn,$select10);
while($asso = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select100)) {
$distancecp1 = getDistance(''.$villeselect.', '.$cpselect.'',''.$asso['ville'].', '.$asso['codep'].'');
$distancecp2 = array($distancecp1);
asort($distancecp2);
foreach($distancecp2 as $distancecp){
    echo ''.$distancecp.' ';
}
}
```

My echo returns me well my 4 values but not ranked in ascending order :(

Comment: For starters, there's no point in putting a single item into an array and then doing a `foreach` loop over it. Second, what have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic simpleXML working example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893024/basic-simplexml-working-example)

Comment: @miken32 Yes I have tried to solve the problem it is 2 weeks that I pluck my hair on this problem of which I can not find the solution :/ Now I am bald lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully at your `var_dump` output: it's not printing a list of all your results, but is called multiple times, each time saying "array (size=1)". That "size=1" is your clue: you have a list with one thing in it, created with `array($something)`. If you sort a list with one thing in it, you will just get the same list, with the same thing in it.

What you need to do instead is create *one* array for the whole loop, and add *all* the items to it:

```
$results = array();
while ( ... ) {
    $distancecp1 = ...
    $results[] = $distancecp1;
}
var_dump($results);
```

Then:

- see here for appropriate sorting methods: [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)
- to turn a SimpleXMLElement object into just a value, you write `(string)$element`