# How to solve PHP Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 4: parser error

Tags: php, xml, parsing

This is my first experience of parsing a xml file with php. I am getting following error when trying to print the results.

[02-May-2020 08:24:13 UTC] PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 4: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in ..../xml.php on line 62

```
<?php

$myXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ici-import xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://journals.site.com/ic-import.xsd">
  <journal issn="xxx-xxx"/>
  <issue number="2" volume="1" year="2019" publicationDate="2019-12-08T11:19:14Z" numberOfArticles="2">
    <article>
      <type>ORIGINAL_ARTICLE</type>
      <languageVersion language="en">
        <title>First Title</title>
        <abstract>test</abstract>
        <pdfFileUrl>http://test.com/download/40</pdfFileUrl>
        <publicationDate>2019-12-08T00:00:00Z</publicationDate>
        <pageFrom>17</pageFrom>
        <pageTo>37</pageTo>
        <doi/>
        <keywords>
          <keyword>test 1</keyword>
          <keyword>test 2</keyword>
        </keywords>
      </languageVersion>
      <authors>
        <author>
          <name>First</name>
          <surname>last</surname>
          <email>author@gmail.com</email>
          <order>1</order>
          <instituteAffiliation>World</instituteAffiliation>
          <role>AUTHOR</role>
        </author>
      </authors>
    </article>
    <article>
      <type>ORIGINAL_ARTICLE</type>
      <languageVersion language="en">
        <title>Second Title</title>
        <abstract>test</abstract>
        <pdfFileUrl>http://test.com/download/41</pdfFileUrl>
        <publicationDate>2019-12-08T00:00:00Z</publicationDate>
        <pageFrom>22</pageFrom>
        <pageTo>26</pageTo>
        <doi/>
        <keywords>
          <keyword>test 1</keyword>
          <keyword>test 2</keyword>
        </keywords>
      </languageVersion>
      <authors>
        <author>
          <name>First</name>
          <surname>last</surname>
          <email>author@gmail.com</email>
          <order>1</order>
          <instituteAffiliation>World</instituteAffiliation>
          <role>AUTHOR</role>
        </author>
      </authors>
    </article>
  </issue>
</ici-import>';
$xml=simplexml_load_string($myXML) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$xmlElement = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
print_r($xmlElement);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create an XML element from the loaded XML data in

```
$xmlElement = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
```

by the time you get to this line, `$xml` is already a SimpleXMLElement.

You can just use the result of `simplexml_load_string()` to work with...

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($myXML) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please add some code to parse any of the elements from my given xml. It will help me to get start.

Comment: I don't know what data you are after, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893024/basic-simplexml-working-example shows some basic usage.